# Are Shimano 105 R7000 STI levers compatible with the older R5800 deraillers?

Tags: shimano, shifter, compatibility

My bike currently has Shimano 105 5800 components (shifters, rim brakes, derailleurs), and I've recently discovered that both my shifters are wearing out.

The derailleurs seem to be in good shape, though.  I'd like to just upgrade the shifters to the newer R7000. Will they work with the older derailleurs and rim brakes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short and easy answer - yes.

Shimano compatibility charts show ST-R7000 shifters are compatible with FD-5800 front derailleur and RD-5800 rear derailleur. All Shimano road rim caliper brakes are compatible with each other.

http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7?cid=C-453&acid=C-455

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about this compatibility chart. Thank you!

Comment: Update: I ended up upgrading to the Ultegra R8000 shifters and things have been great!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, not all shimano road calipers have the same pull, but newest sora and up all have the same Super SLR cable pull. As a general rule, all their shift/brake brake levers with the gear housing run under the tape are compatible. Older levers, new Claris, last gen Sora have the old shorter pull ratio, which most other brands use.

The longer pull Super SLR levers will feel very firm and lack power with shorter pull calipers. Short pull levers with the longer pull calipers will feel mushy and need to be run very close to the rim, but will stop harder if the lever doesn’t bottom out. It’s more subtle than the difference with v-brake MTB levers, but same idea.